# How to extend vendor package service provider in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a package that integrates Xero accounting.

They have a file called `XeroServiceProvider.php` in the following location: `/vendor/drawmyattention/xerolaravel/Providers/XeroServiceProvider.php`.

I need to extend this service provider in my application but I don't like the idea of editing this file directly.

Is there a way I can extend this service provider easily without updating vendor files?

Here is the file I need to extend:

```
namespace DrawMyAttention\XeroLaravel\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use \App\Invoice;

class XeroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    private $config = 'xero/config.php';

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../config.php' => config_path($this->config),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('XeroInvoice', function(){
           //return new \XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice();
           return new Invoice();
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Run `php artisan make:provider ExtendedXeroServiceProvider`

Add it to `./config/app.php` under `providers`

Open `./app/Providers/ExtendedXeroServiceProvider.php`

Change `extends ServiceProvider` to `extends XeroServiceProvider`

Add `use DrawMyAttention\XeroLaravel\Providers\XeroServiceProvider` to it as well

Add the original service provider to the discovery blacklist in `./composer.json`

**EDIT**

as of the time of writing, the `drawmyattention/xerolaravel` package does not use autodiscovery, but in the event that it does, this can be added to the `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "drawmyattention/xerolaravel"
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: Okay... I follow all of it apart from the discovery blacklist bit... what do I add exactly?

Comment: I double checked, you do not need the blacklist for that specific package

Comment: (since if the package **was** using autodiscovery it would try to load the normal + your extended version of it simultaneously, so in that case you would need to blacklist it, but that is a story for another package :)

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks

Comment: Here are the docs about "dont-discover": https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#package-discovery

Comment: The "dont-discover" doesn't seem to work, the package provider is still loaded

Comment: Okay it's not the name of the Provider that goes in there but the name of the package as can be seen in the doc, edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

based on @Quezler answer

1. I tried adding the provider (class) using namespace then run composer dump-autoload, it did not work
2. I tried adding the third party package (name) then run composer dump-autoload then it worked