# How do I override laravel voyager migration files?

Tags: laravel, voyager

Currently I'm using laravel voyager in one of my laravel projects my issue is that voyager comes with some migration files out of the box these migration files sometimes causes conflicts with my own migration files especially that which creates the users table so how is it that i can modify voyager migration files checking the documentation only tells me how to override views and controllers but nothing about migration files. Can some provide the steps you would take to accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish them using `artisan vendor:publish`, then deleting/modifying the ones you need to.

However, sometime the libraries doesn't allow you to publish all their files. I mounted a quick project and it seems to be the case for **voyager**. Apparently, you can only publish the dummy migrations. In that case, I can see only 3 possibles way:

1. Fix the conflict on your side. It will be the easier and cleaner way.
2. Copy manually the migrations `vendor/tcg/voyager/migrations` to `database/migrations` and use `php artisan migrate` **before** `php artisan voyager:install`
3. Fork the library and do your changes. Not the best, you will have to maintain your fork as well as your app.
4. Copy manually the migrations `vendor/tcg/voyager/migrations` to `database/migrations` then [extend/override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50220159/8068675) `vendor/tcg/voyager/src/VoyagerServiceProvider.php` to force to **not** register the migrations. But I would'nt recommend, since event a minor update could break your app.

**Additional Warning** with the points 2 3 and 4: If you do change e.g. a Voyager column name, the library may use the column name in the library and you may encounter some others problem. I do believe you should adapt **your** migrations and **your** codebase.

Comment: It says publishing complete but where do i find the migration files to edit ?

Comment: I see what your saying it's probably best if I just adjusted the migration files in my migrations folder I'll try the first approach you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue with a different package. Things like creating a categories table (already have one thanks) and adding soft delete column to the users table (it already has it).

The solution I came across was to have a migration that inserts migration entries into the migrations table with exactly the same name as the packages migration file(s).

put these migration inserts into its own migration file, and set that filename to a date before the package migrations.

artisan migrate then will run this first and insert entries that make the migration command thinks the package is already migrated.

Unfortunately it does not seem possible to do this in one hit.  The artisan migrate command seems to load the list of existing migrations and then use it as a filter.  The new migration entries are not read and the migration falls over with (eg) table categories already exists.

Fear not, run migrations again and it will work perfectly.