# How/where is Jetstream's service provider registered?

Tags: laravel

Been digging through Laravel Jetstream and cannot find out how the packages `Laravel\Jetstream\JetstreamServiceProvider` is loaded. It was not published to my App config, as I would normally expect.

I am looking to overwrite some `bootInertia` functionality (namely surrounding the `ShareInertiaData` middleware). I am on the latest version of Laravel/Jetstream.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend vendor package service provider in Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219976/how-to-extend-vendor-package-service-provider-in-laravel-5-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `composer.json` of the package. Laravel will look at your packages after `composer install` (and other commands).

See here:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/e87bfd60ed4ca30109aa73c4d23250c113fe75ff/composer.json#L36

It will load all Providers which are defined by the package:
https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/435fdd23a9992cee27e7b0c873b601427290383a/composer.json#L50